# How to convert a base 64 file to pdf in Datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an API service that gives me a base 64 file but I have to convert it to PDF or another format to store it in a Datalake, how can this be done in Azure DataFactory ???

Answer (score 1):

Data factory doesn't have this function built in, but this sounds like an easy job to program in Azure Functions. Once you have that, you can call the function with the Azure Function Activity to make it part of a more complex ETL.

Hope this helped!

Comment: how can I do this in azure functions?

Comment: I would personally use Python, see here: https://www.snippetbucket.com/python-base64-to-pdf/ And here is an intro to python in azure functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/tutorial-vs-code-serverless-python-01 Good luck!